# Historical Credit Ratings for companies

Tags: database, credit-ratings

I am looking forward to get my master thesis done. I have acces to Thomson Reuters Eikon. Unfortunately, they do not provide a good database with historical credit ratings - at least it is not possible so search for ratings according to specific criteria.

Do you know a good source for historical credit ratings for companies? I need a list for some European companies with their changes in ratings for recent years. Otherwise, I have to change my topic for the thesis. :D

Kind regards,
Tobias Horst

Comment: Can't you explore Archive.org of each rating agency? 

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already downloaded the historical data from the big three agencies. And I also can download a list for every single company via Eikon. Unfortunately this data from Eikon is not complete, so I have to add information. My problem is now: I cannot really open the .xml-files containing the data. I mean... I can open them but I can't read the codes. Does anyone know a tool or software that makes the information readable?

Comment: I'm searching for the same data , could you please tell me how you got it from Eikon?
Thanks in advance